# Embedded database and multiple catalogs

Tags: java, database, h2, hsqldb

I want to create integration tests for my repositories. The production database is Sybase and it consists of multiple catalogs in which there are multiple schemas.

In my code I use multiple queries I am selecting data across different catalogs: ex:

```
select * 
from catalog_a.schema_a.table_1 aa1, catalog_b.schema_a.table_2 ba2
where aa1.c1 = ba2.c2
```

So for the tests I would like to create embedded database, like H2, HSQLDB or something different. I was trying to find something that would allow me to simulate prod db with multiple catalogs, but I couldn't make it work. Please advice and suggest the solution.

I am writing app in java/spring. Additional trick here is that my app is creating only one DataSource to database.

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB supports only a single catalog and the name is checked when the catalog is specified in a query. You can change the catalog name from the default PUBLIC to something else. For example:

```
ALTER CATALOG public RENAME TO to catalog_a
```

But using two different catalog names is not supported.

If your schema or table names in the two catalogs are different, you could modify the source code of HSQLDB and disable the catalog name check for your tests in the method `org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.checkValidCatalogName(String name)`

Comment: Interesting... I might try that. Are you aware of something similar but for H2?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this in H2 via [IGNORE_CATALOGS](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_ignore_catalogs) property and version 1.4.200.

However, the url example from their docs did not seem to work for me, so I added a statement in my schema.xml:

`SET IGNORE_CATALOGS = true;`